# Camera does not work in wkwebview with swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I have use wkwebview for load camera webpage. The webpage is working in safari and android but does not work camera in wkwebview.
I have added permission in plist file. verified on app setting. camera and microphone are enable so till camera does not start on webpage.

Thanks

Comment: [Provide a minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.